# NSubstitute Returns is ignored even when the parameters match

Tags: c#, testing, nsubstitute

I have the `QuerySingleDefinition` method that takes a function `target` and a boolean `enabled`.

I create an `ILicenseChecker` substitute. I then use NSubstitute to override the method `ILicenseChecker.IsEnabled`. I specify that every time`ILicenseChecker.IsEnabled` receives any `User`parameter and a `definition` object with a predefined id, return the value of the `enabled` parameter given to `QuerySingleDefinition`.

I then pass the `licenseChecker` to another substitute `querying`.
`querying` and `definition` are then passed to the `target` function. The target function later uses `querying` which then uses `ILicenseChecker.IsEnabled` on `definition`.

`ILicenseChecker.IsEnabled` does not return the value of the `enabled` parameter given to `QuerySingleDefinition`. It always returns `false``

What am I missing here?

```
public async Task<T> QuerySingleDefinition<T>(Func<IEntityDefinitionQuerying, EntityDefinition, Task<T>> target, bool enabled)
        {
            var definition = await CreateDefinition().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var licenseChecker = Substitute.For<ILicenseChecker>();
            licenseChecker.IsEnabled(Arg.Is<EntityDefinition>(p => p.Id == definition.Id), Arg.Any<User>()).Returns(Task.FromResult(enabled));

            var querying = MApplication.Container.Resolve<IEntityDefinitionQuerying>(new TypedParameter(typeof(ILicenseChecker), licenseChecker));

            return await target(querying, definition).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```